# Guardar coordenadas al hacer clic sobre un mapa de openstreetmaps cargado en un WebView de Android?

Tags: java, android

Buen dia, quiesiera saber como puedo obtener las coordenadas de latitud y longitud  de un mapa de openstreetmaps al hacer clic sobre el. El mapa lo estoy agregando dentro de un WebView en android.
Quisiera que las coordenadas se puedan guardar en una variable para poder utilizarla dentro de la app.

Este es el xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".WebViewMapActivity">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewOSM"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

La actividad

```
public class WebViewMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;
    private HashSet<Point> points;
    String url="https://www.openstreetmap.org";
    private AssetManager assetManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_map);
        assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webviewOSM);
        final WebSettings ajustesVisorWeb=myWebView.getSettings();
        ajustesVisorWeb.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: Creo que no tiene api para android es todo por web.